# Which bitcoin wallet allows me to generate and export a large number of addresses?

Tags: wallet, address-generation

I need a software Bitcoin wallet (not web account based) that allows easy generation of many new payment addresses at once that are ideally stored in plain text, (bulk exported as plain text). The security is not a concern. 
I like Bitcoin-Qt but it is outdated and it takes forever to download the entire chain, which make it not portable in a way.

Is it necessary to download the chain? If one can use a paper wallet than one must be able to use software one without having the blockchain, or having just a small number of blocks, right?

Comment: Have you checked the bitcoin website, https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet , it lets you choose between different wallets.

The idea of downloading the full block chain is to have maximum security,  so its kind of not secure not to download the block chain. 

Saying that there are some SPV clients which let you do without downloading the full blockchain. You can check the mobile version ones for that.

Comment: JDE: This sounds like an XY-problem to me. What do you need the large amount of addresses for? Are you asking how to provide addresses to a webshop setup?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to download blockchain to generate address. Use an HD wallet like electrum, so that you can regenerate wallet using seed even if you lose private keys.

To generate addresses http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-pre-generate-new-addresses
To export addresses use electrum command line http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/cmdline.html

Answer (score 1):

If you program in Java, you can use Bitcoinj to generate addresses. Bitcoinj supports HD wallets, so the addresses are generated from the same seed.

Answer (score 0):

I made this wallet: [Bolt](https://vladimirtahl.github.io/bolt/#) does not need any account.

It saves your private keys encrypted or plain text.

And you can generate as many address you like.